# Grouping columns in Python Pandas pivot table

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

My pivot table has two levels of columns (level 1: adult vs kids, level 2: male vs Female)
For Adults, I want to collapse level 2. How do I convert Pivot table 1 to table 2?

Pivot table 1 (current output)

```
          Adults_____   Kids_______
          Male Female   Male  Female
Count     5      5       12      8
```

Pivot table 2 (desired output)

```
          Adults    Kids_______
                    Male    Female
Count     10         12      8
```

I tried the following which returns a KeyError.

```
df = df[[('Adults'),('Kids','Male'),('Kids','Female')]]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html) and then [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) original column `Adults_____`:

```
print df
      Adults_____        Kids_______       
             Male Female        Male Female
Count           5      5          12      8

df['Adults'] = df['Adults_____'].sum(axis=1)
df = df.drop('Adults_____', axis=1)
df = df[['Adults','Kids_______']]
print df
      Adults Kids_______       
                    Male Female
Count     10          12      8
```

Comment: Thanks!! What is 'axis=1' there for?

Comment: `axis=1` means sum by columns, see [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html)